How to Configure hideAnnouncements in kibana.yml?
In Kibana's GUI settings page, there is an entry called "Hide announcements" with the field named hideAnnouncements.
The URL path for this page is /app/management/kibana/settings
Then in the documentation for the YAML config file there is an entry newsfeed.enabled.
If newsfeed.enabled is set to false, the hide announcements setting in the GUI does not change.
Is there a kibana.yml setting that controls hideAnnouncements?

This is an undocumented feature, but we can look at source code.
For example in kibana/packages/core/ui-settings/core-ui-settings-server-internal/src/settings/announcements.ts, we see:
hideAnnouncements: {
  name: i18n.translate('core.ui_settings.params.hideAnnouncements', {
    defaultMessage: 'Hide announcements',
  }),

We can deduce that hideAnnouncements is part of the UI Settings and the documentation says:

When a setting is configured as an override in kibana.yml, it will override any other value stored in the config saved object. If an override is misconfigured, it will fail config validation and prevent Kibana from starting up. The override applies to Kibana as a whole for all spaces and users and the option will be disabled in the Advanced Settings page. We refer to these as "global" overrides.
Use the top-level uiSettings key for this, for example:
# Display times in UTC
uiSettings:
  overrides:
    "dateFormat:tz": "UTC"


So for hideAnnouncements, you can add in kibana.yml:
uiSettings:
  overrides:
    "hideAnnouncements": true

Beware that this feature is in technical preview:

This functionality is in technical preview and may be changed or removed in a future release. Elastic will work to fix any issues, but features in technical preview are not subject to the support SLA of official GA features.

